# Existe-t-il un mot pour désigner un pays doublement enclavé ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, géographie

Un pays est dit enclavé s'il n'a pas d'accès à la mer.

De manière analogue à "antépénultième" qui est un mot unique pour "précède l'avant-dernier", existe-t-il un mot unique pour désigner un pays "doublement enclavé" (enclavé par des pays n'ayant eux-mêmes aucun accès à la mer) ?

**Edit**, suite aux commentaires. La question n'indique pas que "enclavé" signifie "qui n'a pas accès à la mer", mais que n'ayant pas accès à la mer, un pays peut être défini comme "enclavé" (au moins dans certains contextes).

Egalement, je ne cherche pas une définition pour le terme 'enclavé' (littéralement 'cloué dedans') mais à savoir s'il existe un mot pour "doublement enclavé", soit dans un sens général, soit (et de préférence) pour le contexte d'un pays n'ayant pas d'accès à la mer.

Comment: Un pays est dit « enclavé » s'il n'a qu'un seul pays limitrophe, pas simplement qu'il n'a pas accès à la mer. Le Saint-Marin est enclavé (en Italie) mais le Liechtenstein ne l'est pas, bienqu'il n'ait pas accès à la mer, ses frontières jouxtent deux pays (Suisse et Autriche)

Comment: Cela ne répond pas à la question, mais je ne vois pas d'exemple de pays doublement enclavé.

Comment: @Toto, non il n'y a pas de pays doublement enclavé actuellement. Concernant cette acceptation d'"enclavé" voir ici https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pays_sans_littoral

Comment: C'est en contradiction avec le dictionnaire de l'Académie : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/enclav%C3%A9

Comment: @Toto, Erratum au commentaire précédent. Si, selon cette définition (qui n'est peut être pas bonne) 2 pays sont doublement enclavés le Liechtenstein et l'Ouzbékistan

Comment: « Enclavé » ne signifié pas « qui n'a pas accès à la mer ». C'est au sens large (*lato sensu*) que cet adjectif est utilisé, à mon avis abusivement, dans wikipedia. Il aurait fallu écrire « enclavé dans les terres ».

Comment: @jlliagre, je comprends vos remarques, mais la question porte essentiellement sur "doublement enclavé" et pas sur la signification d'enclavé elle-même (veuillez cependant noter qu'indépendamment de wikipedia, cette signification pour 'enclavé' est utilisée en géopolitique du fait de l'importance de l'éloignement des mers et donc des principaux canaux de transport internationaux de biens commerciaux).

Comment: Ça veut dire quoi doublement enclavé?? Un pays peut être enclavé géographiquement et politiquement, je suppose. Alors, doublement et puis, on l'explique.....il n'y a pas de mot comme cela pour un double sémantisme.

Comment: @Lambie, merci pour ce retour qu' "un double sémantisme" ne correspond pas à un mot en français est déjà une/un début de réponse. Par ailleurs, je pense que "doublement enclavé" est défini dans la question "enclavé par des pays n'ayant eux-mêmes aucun accès à la mer".

Comment: @J'aimerais bien savoir ce que l'on entend par "doublement enclavé"; pour moi, "les enclavements/ages" ne seraient pas du même ordre.

Comment: @Lambie Your astute observation that "*les enclavements/ages* ne seraient pas du même **ordre**" jives (at least in English) with the terms "first-order enclaves" (for normal enclaves); "second-order enclaves" (for jlliagre's *counter-enclaves* /enclaves within an enclave [+1]); and "third-order enclaves" (for *counter-counter enclaves* /enclaves within an enclave within an enclave).

Comment: @PapaPoule What I find annoying about questions like this is lack of context. There is a difference between enclaves that mean no outlet to the sea and enclave referring to the borders of an administrative zone. Grrgh. Anyway, yes, I was right about orders but I also meant ze ozzer zeng.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un terme parfois utilisé pour désigner un pays ou une entité administrative doublement enclavée est « **contre-enclave** ».

Par exemple [ici](http://www.europemaxima.com/une-geographie-pittoresque-par-georges-feltin-tracol/) (Une géographie pittoresque par Georges FELTIN-TRACOL):

> En Europe aussi, on découvre un enchevêtrement d’enclaves et de **contre-enclaves**, en particulier entre les Pays-Bas et la Belgique. Ainsi, « Baarle est un village néerlando-belge. Baarle-Hertog, partie belge de Baarle, est composée de quatre morceaux en Belgique, le long de la frontière entre les deux pays, et de vingt-deux enclaves en territoire néerlandais, au milieu du morceau principal de Baarle-Nassau, qui est la partie néerlandaise de Baarle, elle-même composée d’un morceau principal, de sept **contre-enclaves** dans deux des vingt-deux enclaves de Baarle-Hertog et d’une enclave dans un des morceaux de Baarle-Hertog en Belgique… (p. 18) ». Cette complexité administrative territoriale remonte au Moyen Âge et a toujours été approuvée par les habitants !

Il est possible que « **contre-enclave** » soit inspiré de l'anglais *counter-enclave*.